# Searching across multiple lines

Tags: vim

I have switched to using vim with its very nice plugins for writing a TeX documents. However, the only problem I have is while searching for sequences that span multiple lines. I know I can write `\_s\+` instead of putting spaces but it takes time to do this every time. Regarding this, is there a way to tell vim to replace, on the go, space bar push event with `\_s\+` when we are searching with `/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this.

```
cnoremap <expr> <space> (getcmdtype() is# '/') ? '\_s\+' : ' '
```

Every time a space is encountered it is replaced by `\_s\+` when the command type if `/` or it replaced by a space normally. (If you want this to also work when searching with `?` change the `/` to a `?`)